# Cordova js return wrong date time and utc on Android only on specific device

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, datetime

Cordova js code return wrong datetime and utc on Android, only on specific device (Sony xperia e6553). Mobile time showing correctly, but my app showing wrong on that particular mobile only. I also checked the Date & Time Auto Network Time, Auto time zone settings everything correct. My code

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.toUTCString();
```

returns wrongly like :

```
Tue, 29 Sep 2015 09:25:28 GMT
```

But in all other mobile showing correct value :

```
Tue, 29 Sep 2015 17:55:28 GMT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the cordova globalization plugin as see if that helps.

cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-globalization

Comment: Yes i got it.. Ya I got the Timezone offset value by using ''getDatePattern'' method. Thanks Sarkar..

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me today on Android 7.
Just rebooting the device corrected the issue.